# Why am I getting the "#NAME?" Error in excel for my custom function?

Tags: excel, vba

I have already looked at the other answer on the site and that does not seem to be the issue with mine.
I have named my Module differently from my function.
[As you can see I changed it back to the default after naming it something else did not work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEcOL.png)
Here is the evaluation step where it breaks its the second step.

Second Step:[Boom x2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO9Fq.png)

Am I doing something wrong? Would my code actually cause this because normally that would be a "#VALUE" ?

Comment: Quick test - open a new workbook, and add your function to a module in that. Then see if it runs correctly in that new WB, or if you still get the #NAME error.  OR, rename your funciton to just like `Function testFunc()` and see if that works in your current WB.

Comment: Okay making a new workbook fixed it. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: Unfortunately, not really. It is something with your current workbook.  If you add a new module to your current one, defaulting to "Module2" name, cut and put your function in there (making sure it's gone from Module1). See if it still gives a `#NAME` error.

Comment: Regardless thanks for the assistance. And yea that fixed it as well....

Comment: Odd - I suppose it's something in that specific module that Excel isn't "recalculating".

Answer (score 0):

Just googled upon this old post when I had the same (or a similar) problem.  The same pathology applied.  I worked out in the end that when the Module has the same name as the UDF within, the UDF cannot be called / returns #NAME.  Go figure...